# using signals to save on the django model

Tags: django

i have a video model which used pymovieclip to grab the duration of the video file in and then try to add it to the model being saved. i am able to grab the info with no problem but saving it to the instance does not work

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Video)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    print('Saved: {}'.format(instance.id))
    video = Video.objects.get(pk=instance.id)
    path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT,"{}".format(video.video))
    duration = VideoFileClip(path).duration
    print('Saved: {}'.format(duration))
    actual = round((duration / 60), 2)
    video.video_duration = actual
    `
```

but it doesnt work. adding `".save()"` also puts the server in a loop

Comment: Your save function instantiates another update on the dependent Model which triggers another. Check for the infinite loop case.

Comment: true, i have tried several methods, none seems to work

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to get the Video object again. The instance parameter is already referring to the instance of Video which is being saved.

Try do to:

```
instance.video_duration = actual
instance.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling `instance.save()` on a `post_save` will retrigger the `post_save` signal; thus launching an infinite loop.

You're better off using [pre_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/signals/#pre-save) for your use case of adding the duration on the instance.

The `save()` will be issued after the signal-handler ends so no need to call `save()` again on a `pre_save` receiver/handler.